# Distinguish multiple requests in Jersey Request Filter

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, requestfiltering

I have a class which implements ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter. I am using this class to log the request and the corresponding response to it.I note the start_time in request filter and propagate this to the response filter using MDC.put("start-time",start_time).
I can see that since the response filter takes the ContainerRequestContext as the argument , it is able to map the response to the correct request.

But I am not able to see how the logging filter class is able to distinguish between multiple request calls which would be coming simultaneously. Does each request make a different instance of the logging filter class ?

Comment: Can you paste a sample code to better understand the question? Do you've a custom logging filter to do this?

Comment: Yes I have written a custom logging filter . I have used the following tutorial to write one

[link]http://www.makeinjava.com/custom-logging-filter-using-jersey-containerrequestfilter-containerresponsefilter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does each request make a different instance of the logging filter class ?

No. So trying to store member state is not an option. What you should do is use the `ContainerRequestContext` to set a property on the request side. On the response side just get the property from the same context.

```
// request filter
filter(ContainerRequestContext request) {
  request.setProperty("key", value);
}

// response filter
filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
    Object value = request.getProperty("key");
}
```

Each request will get its own `Container(Request|Response)Context`.

Comment: I am asking how does the RequestFilter distinguish between multiple requests which are coming at the same time. How is the request filter implemented ? How are multiple requests handled by the filter so that no two request context are mixed. 

I am able to set start time using MDC and it works fine . I am also aware that we can set request property to save the state.

Comment: Jersey creates a new context for each request and passes the context to the filter. What else is there to know?